# Centering floated elements with custom width

Tags: css, css-float

Today I am facing a big problem with centering floated elements that have set custom width. For better explanation I made a snippet for you:

```css
body { text-align: center; }
.square {
    width: 20%; height: 100px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    float: left;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square">a</div>
    <div class="square">b</div>
    <div class="square">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="square">a</div>
    <div class="square">b</div>
    <div class="square">c</div>
    <div class="square">d</div>
    <div class="square">e</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that first three squares get shrinked after centering.

The reason why I am floating the elements is that the second container has to be same as first container and it must contain 5 elements (to cover full width of document). Here is how it looks like without floating (see the gabs between elements):

```css
body { text-align: center; }
.square {
    width: 20%; height: 100px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">a</div>
        <div class="square">b</div>
        <div class="square">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">a</div>
        <div class="square">b</div>
        <div class="square">c</div>
        <div class="square">d</div>
        <div class="square">e</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the elements have right width, but the second line doesn't cover width of document because of the gabs between elements.

Is there any way to have floated elements with custom width centered? Which styles I should use for container element?

Comment: square should be inline block and no float, container should be display block.

Comment: @SalmanA The squares MUST be floated, I will edit my post.

Comment: Have you tried adding width:auto in container style and give padding:20px in square to see squares

Comment: @NirjharVermani That is not exactly what I wanted because I wanted squares being exactly 20%x100px.

Comment: @PDKnight I'm just curious why elements should be floated? If you need them 20%, then you have to set some width to parent element.

Comment: @Vel See edited post :)

Comment: @PDKnight Check my edited answer

Comment: @NirjharVermani The result doesn't seem to act as being working: https://jsfiddle.net/vdjk8jd0/4/

Comment: You can't center floats. Floats were not designed to be used for layout. Floats do nasty stuff like becoming out-of-flow, which most probably you don't want. I don't recommend using floats for this. Of course inline-blocks were not designed for layout neither, so you get some spaces between if you are not cautious. If you can, you should use flexbox, which was designed to do this kind of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I think I got what you need

```
.square {
width: 20%; height: 100px;
background: cornflowerblue;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1rem;
}

.container {
display: block;
font-size:0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vel/zn9e4fg5/)

Comment: I will edit my post for better explanation.

Comment: I've edited my code

Comment: That's it, I totally forgot about whitespace between elements (because I've used it years ago). Thank you! Also, this HTML trick works too ;) https://jsfiddle.net/vdjk8jd0/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
body { text-align: center; }
.square {
  width: 20%; height: 100px;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  float: left;

}

.container {
width:100%;
margin-right:20%;
margin-left:20%;
}
```

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Try to give a look at my edited post :)

Answer (score 0):

> Add `min-width:7px;` this will solve your issue

```css
body { text-align: center; }
.square { 
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
    float: left;
    min-width:7px;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">a</div>
        <div class="square">b</div>
        <div class="square">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="square">a</div>
        <div class="square">b</div>
        <div class="square">c</div>
        <div class="square">d</div>
        <div class="square">e</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here your 5 div row era is also working.

Comment: Almost. The elements must be having width set to 20%.

Comment: but why is it so?

Comment: As explained above, I need last row of squares covering full width of document and they must have same width (so, 100%/5=20%).

Comment: I have added the exact thing in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7uotuarr/ . I hope this will help you

Comment: Nah, the elements doesn't have width of 20%.

Comment: check now, i have updated the answer

Comment: No. Anyways, this question is actually solved.

Comment: ok. but what is the problem in this solution?

Comment: Your elements still don't have 20% of width of document.